# Does Intel AX20 bluetooth require antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, m2-connector

I just bought a Intel AX201NGW bluetooth + WIFI card to go on my M2 slot. It didn't come with an antenna, and, while the computer can see the card (as both WIFI and bluetooth), I cannot connect to any networks. Does anyone know if the antenna are required to connect to a network?

Comment: Bluetooth is very short range. The Bluetooth daughter card in my X230 (I replaced it) has no separate antenna. I expect there is a short range antenna built into the card.

Comment: Please check my answer again ,  these was a  mistake in the advice given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every radio needs *some kind* of antenna to function.

What kind of antenna is used is dependent on design choices. The designer might choose to use a tiny "patch" antenna hidden in a small package near the chip or have a longer and better placed antenna connected via an rf connector elsewhere.

WiFi cards, due to their poor placement within a shielded enclosure, tend to expect an external antenna. You should look for a [U.FL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL) connector on your WiFi card. It is the most common small RF connection used.

[image]

In the image below (from [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/intel-ax201ngw-cnvio-interface/p/17Z-0018-00050)) you can see the two antenna connectors on the top right of the card with "1" and "2" written in white text on the card. The manual will tell you which connectors you should use.

[image]

Then you will have to find out if your laptop has a hidden antenna connector, or whether you can find or purchase one designed for your laptop. You may have to disassemble your machine to fit an antenna.

Alternatively you should return the card you bought and get a USB device which can be fitted outside the shielded body of your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

##### Community Revision

Here is an image to help you distinguish different connector form factors. Finding the exact one for your device may be difficult (even Intel's spec sheet does not always contain this information).

[image: different wifi chip antennae]

Search around with your specific model number then buy appropriate item.

---

EDIT: I got this answer wrong! , here is the correction

Yes , you need a **sma antenna** and a **interfacing wire adapter**, consider using an Ipex **MHF4 adapter to female SMA** for **M.2 Devices** such as the (AX200 (normal) / AX201(cnvi 2.0 chipset needed)) https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/IPX-MHF-4-MHF4-plug-to-SMA-female-jack-bulkhead-right-angle-0-81mm-Pigtail-cable/182796975816?_trkparms=aid%3D555021%26algo%3DPL.SIMRVI%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20201208142511%26meid%3D7e6eaaf6b1324ff5893f445410cf06e7%26pid%3D100752%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D11%26mehot%3Dpf%26sd%3D143319767526%26itm%3D182796975816%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DSimplRVIAMLv5WebWithPLRVIOnTopCombiner&_trksid=p2047675.c100752.m1982

***Avoid using this U.FL adapter https://www.ebay.com/itm/6-U-FL-IPX-to-RP-SMA-Female-Antenna-WiFi-Pigtail-Cable-ufl-ipex-1-13mm-Mini-PCI/163471172198?hash=item260fa42266:g:DAgAAOSwPXFcMYsd .This is for PCI-E wifi adapters  (older devices such as intel 7260)***

*PSA: Also for other people ,some newer intel wifi cards  require your laptop/desktop chipset to support CNVI (older versions of cnvi doesnt work with newer versions i.e using 9560 to upgrade to ax201).You can use the non cnvi cards for devices with chipsets before Gemini Lake (desktop) & Coffee Lake(laptop) such as Intel AX200.

Edit: The U.FL connector is good for 6ghz , any higher frequency you will need a new antenna/cable and terminated connector.